# Can I use Pub/Sub model with Many Publishers and Only One Subscriber?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I need to send some files from different machines to only one Server. As I understand, I can use JMS api + (for example) ActiveMQ as broker. There are two models: p2p and pub/sub. I would like to use pub/sub model, but the problem is that I haven`t few subscribers, I have only one Subscriber(Server) and many Publishers. The question is the following: can I use pub/sub model for my situation and How can I send files from different machines to Only One Topic, on that Server sibscribed? May be any other ideas, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can but I don't see the advantage of using a topic instead of a queue when there is only one reader.